# Cross compiling Mesa for arm

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, mesa

I have cross compiled Qt5.9.1 for an arm linux platform. I see that qtwebengine because `mesa/libegl1-mesa-dev` is missing.
I am relatively new to linux and i have been trying to cross compile mesa12, mesa13 and mesa17. But all failed.

Is libegl1-mesa-dev absolutely necessary to build qtwebengine to work on linuxfb ? If so, can anyone provide me the dependency list for opengl without x11 and some guiding light to how to cross compile it ?

I came to know that QtWebengine can use software renderer such as QtQuick2drenderer in Qt 5.7. What are the possibilities that i can do the same in Qt 5.9.1 ?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit :** 
Mesa version : 12.0.6
cross compiled dependencies : udev-182 and util-linux-2.30 (for libblkid)
This is the error i am getting :

```
 CCLD     libgbm.la
 ../../src/loader/.libs/libloader.a(libxmlconfig_la-xmlconfig.o): In function `__getProgramName':
xmlconfig.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `__progname'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

configure i have used

```
./configure  CPPFLAGS="-I$INCLUDEPATH -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS" CFLAGS="-I$INCLUDEPATH -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS" LDFLAGS="-L$LIBPATH" --host=$HOST --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-dri3=no --enable-gallium-llvm=no --disable-omx --enable-gallium-tests=no --enable-gallium-osmesa=no -enable-glx=dri --with-gallium-drivers=swrast --with-dri-drivers=swrast --disable-glx --enable-va=no --enable-vdpau=no --with-egl-platforms=drm
```

Comment: how are you building it? enable needed features and you'll see dependancies triggered by qt5

Comment: I am using the newly compiled qmake to use the qtwebengine.pro. Missing dependency is `mesa/libegl1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: I believe you've just answered your question.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Please read my question again. I have already mentioned it in my post. Can you provide me any guidance or links for cross compiling mesa ?

Comment: do you even know what cross-compilation is?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I believe cross compilation is compiling a application on platform A using the toolchain of platform B, so that the output of this compilation works on the target platform B.

Comment: that is pretty accurate; so, what except cross compiler do you need?

Comment: During the cross compiling of mesa, this is the error i am getting :
` CCLD     libgbm.la
../../src/loader/.libs/libloader.a(libxmlconfig_la-xmlconfig.o): In function `__getProgramName':
xmlconfig.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `__progname'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: edit your question and clearly explain the problem you're having, with all the logs!

Comment: Yes @OleksandrKravchuk, i have done that. Do go through it and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `__progname` is defined in xmlconfig.c and i think it is not linked with libloader.a. I don't know how to establish this link.